# Getting Input From a Tkinter Class by Another Class

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am trying to connect my tkinter code with another program. That is, I am trying to call the GUI file from the the other program and receive input from the GUI program, but I am having issues.
Here is the GUI code called BayeGUI

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.simpledialog
class BayeGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title('Graphical User Interface Designed by Gideon')
        self.input = 'I am fine Thank you' 
        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()
        self.v1 = StringVar()
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame1)
        scrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
        self.text = Text(frame1, width = 100, height = 30,wrap = WORD, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.config(command = self.text.yview)
        self.text.pack()
        
        frame2 = Frame(window)
        frame2.pack()
        testbtn = Button(frame2,text = 'Test Algorithm',command = self.testAlgorithm)
        testbtn.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        
        return self.input
        window.mainloop()
        
        

    def testAlgorithm(self):
        isYes = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno('askyesno', 'Do you want to Test the Algorithm?')
        if isYes == True:
            self.input = self.text.get("1.0",'end-1c') #This is the input I need
BayeGUI()
```

This is the main code where I am trying to get value fron Baye GUI.

```
from BayeGUI import BayeGUI

emails = BayeGUI()
print(emails)
```

Comment: You cannot return value inside `__init__()` function.  Also two instances of `BayeGUI` will be created: one from `from BayeGUI import BayeGUI` as `BayeGUI()` is called inside `BayeGUI.py`, one from `emails = BayeGUI()` after the first instance is closed.

Comment: What does _"I am having issues"_ mean? What issues are you having?